# Can't get form total cost

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So I have a form with two dropdowns. The first dropdown is the options, and the other is more options. So it's like a mix and match, now I want to calculate the total from the two selected dropdowns. Here's what I got going

```
var repairCost = new Array();
    repairCost["none_repair"] = 0;
    repairCost["minor"] = 10;
    repairCost["major"] = 20;
    repairCost["extreme"] = 30;

    var colorCost = new Array();
    colorCost["none_color"] = 0;
    colorCost["single_portrait"] = 10;
    colorCost["group_scene"] = 20;

    $("#repair_drop").change(function (event) {
        getRepair();
        function getRepair(){
            var repair = 0;

            var form = document.forms["myform"];
            var selectedRepair = form.elements["repair_drop"];
            repair = repairCost[selectedRepair.value];

            return repair
        }
    });

    $("#colorize_drop").change(function (event) {
    getColor();
    function getColor(){
            var color = 0;

            var form = document.forms["myform"];
            var selectedColor = form.elements["colorize_drop"];
            color = colorCost[selectedColor.value];

            return color
        }
    });
    var timer1 = null;
    clearTimeout(timer1); 
    timer1 = setTimeout(total, 500)

    function total(){
        var cost = getRepair() + getColor();
        console.log(cost);
    }
    total();
```

I end up getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getRepair is not defined

So for example I'd choose `repairCost["minor"]` and `colorCost["group_scene"]`, then my result would be `$30`. I have a timer in there so it automatically calculates the total. Any ideas?

Comment: Move `getRepair` method outside of the `$("#repair_drop").change` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the `getRepair` function inside another function. Therefore you cannot access it from outside. You have to define it outside the function to be able to access it, like so :

```
var repairCost = new Array();
repairCost["none_repair"] = 0;
repairCost["minor"] = 10;
repairCost["major"] = 20;
repairCost["extreme"] = 30;

var colorCost = new Array();
colorCost["none_color"] = 0;
colorCost["single_portrait"] = 10;
colorCost["group_scene"] = 20;

function getRepair(){
    var repair = 0;

    var form = document.forms["myform"];
    var selectedRepair = form.elements["repair_drop"];
    repair = repairCost[selectedRepair.value];

    return repair;
}

function getColor(){
    var color = 0;

    var form = document.forms["myform"];
    var selectedColor = form.elements["colorize_drop"];
    color = colorCost[selectedColor.value];

    return color;
}

$("#repair_drop").change(function (event) {
    getRepair();

});

$("#colorize_drop").change(function (event) {
    getColor();
});

var timer1 = null;
clearTimeout(timer1); 
timer1 = setTimeout(total, 500)

function total(){
    var cost = getRepair() + getColor();
    console.log(cost);
}
```

Comment: The timer stops calling the `total` function after two rounds. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to look at `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`. `setTimeout()` only runs your function once.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you declaring functions within your events, and then calling them from there? Either declare them outside the events, or just inline the code - don't do both.